# Image doesnt render on animation

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm working with images. The print below is my blender work in viewport shading and the image appears being well.

[image: Viewport Shading]

When i use eevee to render my animation, the image disappear and i don't know why.

[image: Render Animation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it isn’t entirely clear in your description, my guess is that your image is a reference image or a background image. These images are used to assist with modeling in the viewport and are not part of the final render.

If this is the case, there are a few ways to put an image in your scene. First, you can put an [image on a plane using the import images as planes add on](https://youtu.be/mc8Ws9Ngjx8), and position the plane where you want it. Or you can use [compositing](https://henryegloff.com/how-to-render-a-background-image-in-blender-2-8/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks andesign!